# Is there a way to collect all the TODO in the code in one file before push

Tags: git, github, todo

I want store all my TODOs in the code on github, but also I want collect it in one file so I can show them all in one place to my colleagues. Maybe someone solve this task already? With git hooks maybe?

Comment: How would you approach collecting them in one file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you have some specific pattern for your TODOs you can simply `grep` them.

```
grep -R TODO . > todo.txt
```

The next step is to decide when you want this file to be updated. If you want this to happen before push, you'll need at least `git` 1.8.2, since `pre-push` hook [was added](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.2.txt) in this release.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I miss simplest way as always :)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Todofy (https://todofy.org), it lists out all the todos in the repository after integration, and keep tracking its state un till its finished (removed from code). It provides more features like adding deadline, reminders, assigning someone or bringing someone to discussion, labels etc.

Example comment with prettifiers (C++ style comment)

```
// TODO: something has to be done quickly @deadline: 1 week
// @assign: mebjas @priority: high
```

Also it has an inbuilt option to auto create issues in Github.